# Phase Difference Between dynamic voltage and input current

Tags: ac, phase, lcr

I have a RLC circuit, and I know if we wish to calculate the phase difference between Voltage and Input current then the formula is

$$ \phi = \tan^{-1} \frac{X_L -X_C}{R} $$

But as we already know, phase difference between inductor voltage and input current is 90°. I know how to calculate it through waveform. $$\phi = 360  f \,\mathrm dT $$

But I have no idea how do I calculate it through first formula. In short, what will be the question mark in the following expression and why?
$$\phi = \tan^{-1} \frac{X_L}{?}$$.

Also for the capacitor voltage and input current.

I know am weak in electronics and my basics too that's why am seeking help from you guys, kindly  correct me if I was wrong in any of my presumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *But I have no idea how do I calculate it through first formula.*

For a pure inductor the phase relationship between voltage and current is that current **always** lags voltage by 90°. This comes from the basic but fundamental inductor, voltage and current equation: -

$$V = L\dfrac{\mathrm di}{\mathrm dt}$$

Or, if you insist on using your original formula, `ARCTAN(infinity)=90 degrees`. It's infinity because \$X_L/0\$ is infinity and this is because resistance is 0 Ω.

Similarly for the pure capacitor, the phase relationship is that current leads voltage by 90°.

Comment: Thanks sir and one more follow up query, if there is practical inductor suppose I have inductor with internal resistance 10 ohm them the formula will be $$X_L / 10 $$ right?

Comment: @Elecguy oops, sorry I missed your follow-up. Yes the ARCTAN operates on that.